# Remove or customize legend in tmap "view" mode

Tags: r, tmap

I'm creating an interactive map in view mode with tmap package. Can someone please help me to remove the legend from tmap. I understand that tm_layout options do not work for "view" mode. So, what is the way to remove the legend from view mode? Or is there a way to customize the legend so that it only appears once outside the map?

Here is the code I have used:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)
```

```
KL_raw <- read_excel("KL.xlsx")
```

```
dput(KL_raw)
```

```
structure(list(Location = c("Alleppey", "Alleppey", "Alleppey", 
"Calicut", "Calicut", "Calicut", "Ernakulam", "Ernakulam", "Ernakulam", 
"Idukki", "Idukki", "Idukki", "Kannur", "Kannur", "Kannur", "Kasargod", 
"Kasargod", "Kasargod", "Kochi", "Kochi", "Kochi", "Kollam", 
"Kollam", "Kollam", "Kottayam", "Kottayam", "Kottayam", "Malappuram", 
"Malappuram", "Malappuram", "Palakkad", "Palakkad", "Palakkad", 
"Pathanamthitta", "Pathanamthitta", "Pathanamthitta", "Thrissur", 
"Thrissur", "Thrissur", "Trivandrum", "Trivandrum", "Trivandrum", 
"Wayanad", "Wayanad", "Wayanad"), Year = c(2021, 2022, 2023, 
2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 
2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 
2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 
2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023), Mobility = c(4, 
13, 25, 35, 88, 131, 35, 85, 183, 3, 14, 15, 6, 20, 25, 0, 3, 
6, 12, 23, 29, 8, 21, 40, 35, 53, 110, 2, 20, 48, 7, 14, 24, 
6, 10, 15, 29, 102, 132, 87, 75, 116, 3, 7, 15), X = c("8497384.983310532", 
"8497384.983310532", "8497384.983310532", "8435275.170162767", 
"8435275.170162767", "8435275.170162767", "8490794.745767247", 
"8490794.745767247", "8490794.745767247", "8567229.95496439", 
"8567229.95496439", "8567229.95496439", "8390572.602244912", 
"8390572.602244912", "8390572.602244912", "8347955.357610422", 
"8347955.357610422", "8347955.357610422", "8487598.670420328", 
"8487598.670420328", "8487598.670420328", "8526567.264133664", 
"8526567.264133664", "8526567.264133664", "8518408.78234175", 
"8518408.78234175", "8518408.78234175", "8469184.509474115", 
"8469184.509474115", "8469184.509474115", "8532870.85398816", 
"8532870.85398816", "8532870.85398816", "8547909.900739763", 
"8547909.900739763", "8547909.900739763", "8484020.614609588", 
"8484020.614609588", "8484020.614609588", "8565745.942463793", 
"8565745.942463793", "8565745.942463793", "8472342.086830465", 
"8472342.086830465", "8472342.086830465"), Y = c("1062220.305235952", 
"1062220.305235952", "1062220.305235952", "1259936.576874495", 
"1259936.576874495", "1259936.576874495", "1117112.2947996475", 
"1117112.2947996475", "1117112.2947996475", "1102450.522637486", 
"1102450.522637486", "1102450.522637486", "1331665.0532438054", 
"1331665.0532438054", "1331665.0532438054", "1403149.788617227", 
"1403149.788617227", "1403149.788617227", "1115243.7149433082", 
"1115243.7149433082", "1115243.7149433082", "993415.5871096748", 
"993415.5871096748", "993415.5871096748", "1072771.6322972549", 
"1072771.6322972549", "1072771.6322972549", "1237056.8643535364", 
"1237056.8643535364", "1237056.8643535364", "1205892.1224562458", 
"1205892.1224562458", "1205892.1224562458", "1035996.3714154225", 
"1035996.3714154225", "1035996.3714154225", "1178354.0909352647", 
"1178354.0909352647", "1178354.0909352647", "948415.1484541291", 
"948415.1484541291", "948415.1484541291", "1313307.407647557", 
"1313307.407647557", "1313307.407647557")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -45L))
```

```
KL <- KL_raw %>% mutate(X = as.numeric(X), Y = as.numeric(Y))
```

```
KL_sf <- st_as_sf(KL, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 3857)
```

[image: Output]

I need the legends on the top right corner (panels with color coded 2021-2023) removed. From html developer tools, I could identify that these panels fall under "leaflet" function but any functions associated with tm_leaflet do not work on view mode. I do not have any coding/ data science background. I just have very basic knowledge of using R for data visualization. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It will be easy to help you out if you can provide the data `KL_raw` in `dput()` format and also add the libraries you are using. Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question. Apologies. I do not have coding/ data science background. It took me a while to understand how to make my code reproducible. Please let me know if there is anything else I can add/ improve?

Comment: I have copy pasted the exact way it appears. I have also added dput() for the previous versions of the dataset. I'm able to copy the structure and reproduce it on a new file. So, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the legend in `tmap_mode("view")`, you can use the following code

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)

KL <- KL_raw %>% mutate(X = as.numeric(X), Y = as.numeric(Y))
KL_sf <- st_as_sf(KL, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 3857)

tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(KL_sf)+
  tm_dots(col = "Year",
             size = "Mobility",
             border.col = "black",
             border.lwd = 2, legend.show = FALSE)+
  tm_facets("Year",
            nrow = 1,
            sync = FALSE)
```

[image]

Or if you want to place the legend in empty space at the bottom left you can use

```
tm_shape(KL_sf)+
  tm_dots(col = "Year",
          size = "Mobility",
          border.col = "black",
          border.lwd = 2, legend.show = T)+
  tm_facets("Year",
            nrow = 1,
            sync = FALSE) +
  tm_view(view.legend.position = c("left", "bottom"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I greatly appreciate your help